# Reading Excel Spreadsheet and adding information to it

Tags: excel, powershell

I currently have a spreadsheet with the following display:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|    Site    |  UserP  |UserName |
+------------+---------+---------+
| Site A     |  Read   | user1   |
|            |         |         |
+------------+---------+---------+
| Site A     |  Write  | user2   |
|            |         |         |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

The problem is that sometimes the UserName field brings a Group and then I have to open this group and create a new row for each user in this group with the same information.

So if I had this:

```
Site A | Read | Group 1
```

It would become this:

```
Site A | Read | Group 1

Site A | Read | Group 1 User A 

Site A | Read | Group 1 User B

Site A | Read | Group 1 User C
```

I can manually pull the information from the group, the thing is that I don't know how to read a specific column from excel and then create a new row in that excel sheet.

I didn't post any code cause I barely have one. I don't know how to loop to the cells.

This is what I have.

```
$file = "\Desktop\AccessReviewReportPRE.csv" 

$sheetName = "AccessReviewReportPRE" 

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file) 

$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
```

Now, I know how to access individual cells, like this:

```
$worksheet.cells.Item(3, 3).text
```

Just not sure how to loop trough all rows, check what is in the third column and do a action on that.

Following @BenH tip, I did this:

```
$file = "\Desktop\AccessReviewReportPRE.csv" 
$fileContent = Import-csv $file -header "URL", "Site/List/Folder/Item", "Title/Name", "PermissionType",  "Permissions", "LoginName"
$newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{"URL" = 'sdfs'; "Site/List/Folder/Item" = 'dsfd'; "Title/Name" = 'sdf'; "PermissionType" = 'dsf'; "Permissions" = 'sdfs'; "LoginName" = 'sdf'}
$fileContent += $newRow

$fileContent | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "\Desktop\AccessReviewReportAFTER.csv"
```

But it is duplicating the header. Any ideas why?

Comment: Waht powershell code have you got so far, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Use [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) to convert the sheet to an object, make the changes and export?

Comment: I edited with with the little I have

Comment: @Benh Thanks for the tip. I did that and it worked. The only thing is that my header is duplicating. Do you know why? I will edit my question with the code

Comment: If you already have a header in the file, then you don't need to use the `-header` parameter in the import.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through each Row you need a loop.
I recommend a do-while.

```
#My Code to find a groupname
$WorkBook=$Excel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)
#Selcet the first Tabelle
$mappe = $workbook.sheets.item(1)
$Target = $mappe.Range("A1").Find($Grouname)
$start = $Target.Row
end, $middle, $counter = 0
do {
      #assigning
      $middle = $end
      #Search Funktion
      $nextFind = $mappe.Range("A1:A150000").FindNext($Target)
      #Old Range assinging to $find
      $Target = $nextFind
      #Assign the Rownumber
      $end = $nextFind.Row
      #Check if the Value is correct
      if ($mappe.cells.Item($nextFind.Row,1).Value() -eq $Groupname) 
      {
          $counter++
      }else{
          break
      }
}while($end -gt $start)
#The FindNext function only works when there are at least 2 of the groups
#but in some cases there is only 1 group. To fix the issue a counter counts
#the passages and if it is 1, $middle will be assigned the start row.
  if($counter -eq 1)
  {
      $middle= $start
  }
#Because a line must be added after the last one, $row needs be increased by 1
$row = $middle + 1
#Column stays the same, later it will be increased
$column = $Target.Column
# ADD ROW    
$eRow = $mappe.cells.item($row,1).entireRow       
$active = $eRow.activate()
$active = $eRow.insert()
```

With this Code, I'm looking for a Group. The Finde function which I use helps me to locate the group. The finde function does not work in a loop, that's why you must use the FindeNext function.
$middle contains the last row number to add a row it must be increased. 
In order to add data into multiple columns, the row has to stay the same, but the column must be increased.

```
    $mappe.Cells.Item($row, $column) = Text
    $column++
```

If you wanna check the 3 column and based on its value you wanna make an action, make a if-statment.
I know the Code ain't perfect, but I hope it helped.